# Bluetooth Chip Antenna Tack Impedance

Tags: bluetooth

I am using the SparkFun schematic to connect a Bluetooth Microcontroller with a chip antenna as shown below,
[image]

url: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/2/b/7/4/d/SparkFun_Edge_Schematic.pdf

The track impedance for the trace between RFIOP and A1 must be 50 ohms. Does this 50 ohm include the inductors and capacitors along the way?

Also can any one point me to a good document that provides guidelines about laying out Bluetooth chip antenna PCB tracks?

Thanks.

Comment: If you assume the source is 50 ohms, and the antenna is 50 ohms, those component reactances would seem to suggest a good match at 5.6 GHz....not 2.4 GHz. So either assumptions are wrong, or there exists missing reactances embodied by the PCB.

Comment: @glen_geek can you please let me know how you calculated the 5.6 GHz frequency? That will be very helpful. Thanks.